# HTML special characters for languages

Tags: html, unicode

Is there any way to type this word `"हिन्दी中文(简体)"` in html?
I see that there's codes for special characters in html for example for "العربية" `&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;`
But I can't find these codes for this `"हिन्दी中文(简体)"`

Answer (score 3):

There are [tools out there that can do this conversion from raw Unicode symbols to encoded HTML entities](http://mothereff.in/html-entities).

```
&#x939;&#x93F;&#x928;&#x94D;&#x926;&#x940;&#x4E2D;&#x6587;(&#x7B80;&#x4F53;)
```

Comment: Edited the answer to point to an HTML entity conversion tool that actually works. (The previous link would give incorrect results for astral Unicode symbols, [or Unicode code points that are special-cased in HTML](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#tokenizing-character-references)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write “हिन्दी中文(简体)” as “हिन्दी中文(简体)” in HTML. Naturally, you need a character encoding that lets you do that, primarily UTF-8, but that’s a good idea anyway.

You can write any character using a character reference like `&#x939;` (for U+0939 DEVANAGARI LETTER HA, “ह”), but this increases the data size and makes the HTML code look very obscure.

Comment: +1, although “makes the HTML code look very obscure” is subjective. As someone who is unable to read Devanagari I’d actually prefer [the HTML-entity-encoded version here](http://mothereff.in/html-entities#%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%28%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93%29).